# Row count and space usage in sql CE databases

Tags: sql-server-ce, record-count

Hi I have two  DB1.sdf and DB2.sdf file (sql ce).  I want to compare the two. 
I want to check the no of rows and the space used in each of the database.

Is there any way to do that?   Also is there any way to to a corresponding table to table comparision in the two databases?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to try to get row count:

```
public Int64 GetRowCount(string tableName)
{
   object value = ExecuteScalar("SELECT CARDINALITY FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES WHERE PRIMARY_KEY = 1 AND TABLE_NAME = N'" + tableName + "'");
    if (value != null)
    {
       return (Int64)value;
    }
    return -1;
 }
```

If that fails, you can use "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table"

Space used is not available, but you can estimate based on this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827968

For data comparision, the best approach would probably be to migrate each sdf to a SQL Server Express database, and use a SQL Server Data Compare tool